# Have you never loved again

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning, cinema

I am trying to understanding the lyrics of Django Unchained 2012 soundtrack and in one line there is a phrase.

"Django, have you never loved again?"

Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of it. According to English Gramma rules it is in the past perfect tense but it is a question and there should not be never. As I know never speak of an action that has not occurred and what is the meaning of using it next to again (which speaks about future) in the context of a question and in the past perfect tense?

Could any native speaker elucidate this for me?

Source: http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Luis_Bacalov:Django

Comment: 'Loved' is used in the less usual sense of 'had a loving relationship' here. The previous relationship obviously had an end-point. This justifies the punctive use of the **present** perfect with 'again'. "Have you never had another loving relationship since that one ended?"

Comment: Song lyrics are generally considered off-topic here as there are more important considerations in song such as meter and rhyme.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I tried to look up 'punctive' and struggled. OED says 'rare' and has one single line on it, a quotation from 1612. Respect for tenaciously hanging on to such a rarity.

Comment: @Nigel J Others have pointed this out in the past. There's even a question about the word. I've already linked to linguistics articles using the term. 'Punctual' is the more common synonym, but has a more obvious drawback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a native speaker. To understand the meaning, try substituting 'not ever' for 'never'.

Not ever - is what 'never' means.

Not at any time. https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=meaning+never&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

'Djaaango - have you not ever loved again?'

Django - 'no I have never loved again. Not ever!'

It means he has loved, but subsequent to that, he has never (or 'not ever') loved again.

And from your question - 'do not ever speak of an action that has not occurred'

Means the same as:

'Never speak of an action that has not occurred'.

I think if you generally try separating 'never' into 'not ever', it will help you to understand the meaning more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect, as you say, refers to the past relative to when the sentence is made. 'Again' speaks of the future, but it is the future relative to some reference point that is known or implicit.

Thus:

> I went to the shops yesterday. Then I went again.

The second visit to the shops happened after the first, but before the speaker said the sentence.

Thus the lyric means that Django loved once, in the past, but he did not love after that (at least up until the time the sentence is spoken).